# My milk chocolate is grainy - how to fix it?

Tags: chocolate, candy

Below is the milk chocolate recipe I used. It's good enough, but grainy, not as smooth as I'd like. Any thoughts on how to make it smoother? Most recipes I find online have milk chocolate as an ingredient, and don't have milk chocolate as the final product.

Ingredients

---

50 g coconut oil

30 g cocoa powder

50 g powdered sugar

30 g dried milk powder (whole milk, Nido brand)

⅛  teaspoon salt

Directions

---

Melt coconut oil in double boiler

Add cocoa powder, powdered sugar

Mix

Add dried milk powder and salt

Mix

Pour into mold

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sylvia-

Hi! The graininess may be caused by either ingredients or method. When making chocolate, I choose to use cocoa butter as opposed to other fats. It marries with the cocoa powder in a way that other ones seem to have problems with. Furthermore, I choose to combine the cocoa butter and cocoa powder with a violent whisk prior to the addition of heat, to ensure that it is mixed very well before cooking together. Once the consistency is correct through cooking over the boiling water, I remove from the heat and add the sweeteners and milk, also adding salt to taste. Removing from heat isn’t necessarily required, but I find that it is less likely to roast on me.

Another note is that it would do well to give your course ingredients a whirl in a grinder or food processor. I use granulated sugar, or other times, unprocessed sugar. Both of these course ingredients get a good amount of time with blades to create a finer product. Seeing as you are using powdered sugar, this shouldn’t be a problem - unless it becomes lumpy.

Comment: Thanks for this. I haven't seen cocoa butter in stores, maybe I'll have to find it online. My chocolate tastes pretty decent to me, even though it's grainy. Though I've seen lots of info online saying that to make "real" chocolate you need to go through a whole different process (making the cocoa powder much finer).